# Prototype - How to deselect the selected value from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

How do I deselect the selected value from a dropdown list using Prototype.

**From**

```
<select id=“mylist” MULTIPLE >
<option value=“val-1”>Value 1</option>
<option value=“val-2” SELECTED>Value 2</option>
<option value=“val-3”>Value 3</option>
</select>
```

**To**

```
<select id=“mylist” MULTIPLE >
<option value=“val-1”>Value 1</option>
<option value=“val-2”>Value 2</option>
<option value=“val-3”>Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: There is a reason there is almost always a default (usually empty, sometimes 'Please Select' or similar) - something HAS to be selected.

Comment: Your question is describing changing the `selected` DOM property, yet your code example is demanding a change to the `selected` HTML boolean attribute. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: What I have is two dropdowns. If a user selects from one i need to deselect from the other.

Comment: Its also a multi select list which I forgot to mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following code worked well:

```
var options = $$('select#mylist option');
var len = options.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  options[i].selected = false;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what was in my fiddle.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure how to do it in prototype, but I can do it in JavaScript.

For a regular select, set `yourSelectElement.selectedIndex = -1`.

For a multiple select, you can just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on the selected item, but you can do it programmatically as well. See link.

http://jsfiddle.net/kaleb/WxJ9R/

Comment: jQuery also does not do this as well - at least in the limited looking I have done. Both `$("#mySelect").val(null)` and `$("#mySelect").prop("selected",null)` turn the highlight off but do not actually remove the selected property from a select-one. My validation believes mySelect has a selection and allows submit, even though it appears nothing is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can't : you'll have to add an empty option

```
<option></option>
```

and then

```
$$("#mylist option[selected]")[0].selected = false;
$$("#mylist option")[0].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

On the event of the second list being selected...

```
Event.observe('secondlist', 'change', function(){
  if (this.selectedIndex >= 0) 
    $$('#mylist option[selected]').invoke('writeAttribute', 'selected', false);
});
```